# How to Make Undo in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing Coloring Game. Where i am doing coloring the picture. I have done that. But i have to  undo the color . It should revert back .

For eg: windows paint.  Draw and Undo Same Feature.  can any one can post sample code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can use Command pattern

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad topic. There are many ways to solve this.

For pixel-based drawing (as opposed to vector-based), the most straightforward method is to save a copy of the image before each drawing operation. ("Save" in this case means make a copy in memory, not write it to disk.) To undo an operation, revert to the previous version of the image. Even "large" images these days are relatively small compared to the amount of RAM available on a typical machine. Keeping a list of, say, 20 images, giving 20 undo steps, shouldn't be a problem.

For vector-based drawing, keep a `List<>` of objects as they are drawn. To undo, delete the last object that was added.